# Meaning of Graph from tensorBoard

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, histogram

Can someone please help me to interpret the graph from tensorBoard. I have attached the screenshot herewith.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the histogram plot, the distribution plot, or both?

Comment: I am asking about both plot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram plot is just a stack of ordinary [histogram](/questions/tagged/histogram)s, arranged by the `global_step` value that you supplied to the tensorboard writer. One way to think about it is that if the `global_step` value increases in time (such as logging as training proceeds) is that the histogram shows you how the values evolved over time.

The distribution plot is kind of like a [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) arranged by `global_step`. The darker color indicates that the values are closer to the center of the distribution, the paler colors are farther away.